# como crear una tabla con una columna y sus registros fijos

Tags: sql-server

`Hola a todos, soy nuevo en este espacio, mi duda es como puedo crear una tabla la cual siempre muestre una columna con numeros del 1 al 20 fijos para mostrarlos en un select
ya que tengo dos tablas ventas(de ayer y hoy) y cobros(ayer y hoy) con 20 sucursales ventas (hoy) y cobros de (hoy) estan unidas y ventas (ayer) y cobros (de ayer) estan unidas, el problemas es cuando ayer las 20 sucursales hicieron venta y cobro me muestra resultados pero cuando hoy no hicieron venta y cobro no me muestra esa sucursal.
, dejo las tablas

```
`(ventas y cobro del dia de ayer) tabla1       (ventas y cobros del dia de hoy) tabla2
columna id, ventas(ayer),cobro(ayer)  /////////////  columna id, venta (hoy), cobro(hoy)     
1            200          100                         1             0          200      
2            3000        2000                         2            700        1000
3            20000       100                          3             0          800
4            5000        300                          4           12000        200
...                                               ... 
20           7000        200                         20            800         100

al hacer 
select* from tabla1
select* from tabla2
solo me muestra lo siguiente 
columna id, venta+cobro(ayer)      ventas+cobros(hoy)
2             5000                   200
4             5300                   1700
...
20            7200                  900

los valores que estan en 0 o en blanco (vacios) no me los muestra, es por eso que tenia pensado crear una tabla en donde si o si me muestre las 20 sucursales vendan o no vendan y cobren o no cobren, espero hayan entendido y me puedan ayudar
resultado esperado
columnaid, venta+cobro(ayer) ventas+cobros(hoy)
1               300               200
2               5000              1700
3               20100             800
4               5300             12200
...
20              72000             900`
```

sql server, version 2019`

Comment: Hola Eduardo. Si quieres que la gente te siga ayudando te recomiendo que no borres las preguntas tras haber sido contestadas correctamente. Perdemos la reputación conseguida con la respuesta y, además, evita que personas que tengan tu mismo problema puedan beneficiarse de la respuesta y sus explicaciones.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero el escenario.

```
drop table if exists tabla1;
drop table if exists tabla2;
Create table tabla1(id int, [ventas(ayer)] int, [venta (hoy)] int)
Create table tabla2(id int, [cobros(ayer)] int, [cobros (hoy)] int)
Insert into tabla1 (id, [ventas(ayer)], [venta (hoy)])
values
(1,100,200),
(2,100,200),
(3,100,200),
(5,100,200);
Insert into tabla2 (id, [cobros(ayer)], [cobros (hoy)])
values
(3,100,200),
(6,100,200);
```

Las columnas, solo he puesto las que me han parecido y los datos también.

Ahora la solución:

Para esto usaremos un constructor de valores de tabla con 7 filas obligatorias (tú usarás 20).

Y simplemente haremos un `left join` al resto de conjuntos.

```
Select t.columna_id, tabla1.* , tabla2.*
    from (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7))T(columna_id)
    left join tabla1 on t.columna_id = tabla1.id
    left join tabla2 on t.columna_id = tabla2.id;
```

[image: Res]

Si observas el código, nada más hacer el `from` aplicamos un paréntesis y values, con la serie fija de valores, separados por comas y entre paréntesis. Cuando los hemos terminado, llamamos al conjunto como nos parezca y entre paréntesis, le indicamos el nombre de la columna de salida. En el caso `t.columna_id`. Luego solo nos resta hacer un left join con el contenido de las tablas de ventas y cargos.

Esta es una solución muy simple para hacer lo que pides.

Si se usa muchas veces, quizá entonces, deberías pensar en crear una tabla con esos valores.

Comment: Gracias, me ayudo mucho, todo quedo solucionado. saludos.